# NullPointerException Test mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I want to test a method with Mokito but I have some errors... I received NullPointerException

This is the method that I want to test:

```
public String getLastModificationDate(EPTestCase testCase) {
    checkArgument(testCase != null, "TestCase cannot be null.");
    TestCase testCaseDMO = testCaseService.getTestCaseByID(testCase.getUID());
    Date lastModificationDate = testCaseDMO.getLastModificationDate();

    return DATE_FORMAT.format(lastModificationDate);
}
```

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void getLastModificationDataWihtValidTestCase() {
    String testCaseUid = "testCaseUid";
    String lastModificationDate = "16-05-2019 10:39:03";
    EPTestCase testCase = mock(EPTestCase.class);
    TestCase testCaseDMO = mock(TestCase.class);
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = mock(SimpleDateFormat.class);
    Date date = mock(Date.class);
    when(testCaseService.getTestCaseByID(testCaseUid)).thenReturn(testCaseDMO);
    when(testCaseDMO.getLastModificationDate()).thenReturn(date);
    String result = sut.getLastModificationDate(testCase);
    assertEquals(lastModificationDate, result);
}
```

When I debug the test I see that testCaseDMO is null, but I don't know how to fix it. .. I don't understand very well how to test something...

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Most likely, your production code does **not** use the mocked testCaseService your test case created. But we can't know that, as you didn't show us that part of the code. In other words: in order for your mock to be **effective** within your test, it needs to somehow be used by the production code. And as said, your code doesnt give any insights in how that happens (or rather: why it doesnt happen).

Comment: testCaseServise is mock

Comment: That is what you say. Or **assume**? Please understand: do not argue. Simply read [mcve] and ensure that your question contains all relevant information. As of now, it does not.

Comment: @mystique_girl what is it that you're actually trying to test? Usually we don't test mocks. We create the object we want to test and mock all its dependencies. However, your method had only mocks and to me it's not clear which class you're actually testing. Can you please post it in your question? That would make it easier for us to help.